# All data not returning from database on SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Could someone please explain to me why the query below isn't returning all the records matching

`creator_id = 10895`

and then any records which are linked with

`staff_id = 10895` in group table?

It's only returning the record matching `staff_id = 10895`

```
SELECT 
    direct_message.*, 
    IFNULL(direct_message_group.staff_id, 0) as staff_id 
FROM `direct_message` 
INNER JOIN direct_message_group 
    ON direct_message_group.chat_id = direct_message.id 
INNER JOIN direct_message_thread 
    ON direct_message_thread.chat_id = direct_message.id 
WHERE 
( 
    direct_message.recipient_id = '10895' OR 
    direct_message.creator_id = '10895' 
OR (
    direct_message_group.staff_id = '10895' 
    AND direct_message_group.active = '0')
) 
AND direct_message.school_id = '1' 
AND direct_message_thread.school_id = direct_message.school_id 
GROUP BY direct_message.id 
ORDER BY direct_message_thread.inserted DESC 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Images of the tables

[image: Direct Message Group table]

[image: Direct Message table]

[image: Direct Message Thread table]

Comment: Most likely the first inner join should be a left join. As far as I understand it, there might be messages which don't belong to a group. Those would be filtered out by inner join.

Comment: @Mono that's correct, thanks! Put it as an answer if you want to explain it in an answer and i'll tick it as the answer

Comment: It is fine, glad to help. I don't hunt for reputation ;)